# Syntastic working in Vim but not in gVim

Tags: vim, syntax-checking, syntastic

I have Vim (7.3) installed on a Debian (testing), i recently switched to using gVim more than command line Vim (for the colorschemes and undercurl of misspelled words).

Now I coded some Haskell and miss the nice Syntastic errors. And when I type `:SyntasticCheck` nothing happens and if I activate the `ErrorsToggle` function to get a QuickFix window - i get a message:

```
Error detected while processing function ErrorsToggle:

E776: No location list
```

I understand that there is no list that the quickfix window can open, but i don't know why there is none, as i previously invoked `SyntasticCheck`, which should have created a location list.

If I open the same file in command line Vim - everything is all right.
My installed [plugins](https://github.com/epsilonhalbe/dotfiles/blob/master/vim), [.vimrc](https://github.com/epsilonhalbe/dotfiles/blob/master/_vimrc) and [.gvimrc](https://github.com/epsilonhalbe/dotfiles/blob/master/_gvimrc) can be found at github.com.

### Edit:

gVim is working with syntastic if i call `gvim myfile.hs` from the commandline but if I navigate to the file via ex commands and then open the file it is not working.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should install `ghc-mod`:

```
cabal install ghc-mod
```

I had a similar issue and that solved it. It seems that Syntastic uses it:
https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/blob/master/syntax_checkers/haskell.vim (line 18)

Comment: ghc-mod is already installed - otherwise the syntax checker in vim wouldn't work - it is only in gVim where the problem occurs.